# Image not displaying properly from database

Tags: php

My images are sent from mobile device by converting them in base64 and has saved them in my database in text format. Now i am trying to display the image in this way:

```
<img src='data:image/gif;base64," .  $before_pic . "' height='70' width='70' />
```

Image is displaying but not the whole image only partial parts.

[image]

what i am doing wrong and how it needs to be done. The image size is around 500kb and it is displaying smaller size images properly.

Comment: There's a spelling mistake... You gave as 'hieght' change it to 'height'

Comment: Can you provide the code which sends it to database?

Comment: insertion of php code is okay as it displays the images of 40-50kb in a proper manner @AdilAliyev

Comment: How big is the text field you're using? Can it hold a base64 encoded string of that length?

Comment: Can you provide database structure. What column type do you use for encoded image and what is the size of column?

Comment: i have assigned the data type to text only in my phpmyadmin

Comment: @Fay007 And you're aware that base64 is larger than a regular string, and a `TEXT` field "only" can hold `65,535` bytes (64 KB)? Most people store files on the server and paths in the database instead (which is also what `BLOB` and `LONGBLOB` does, except it returns the data from the file, rather than the path - the only difference is in the backend of MySQL).

Comment: what if i change the type to medium text @h2ooooooo

Comment: @Fay007 A `MEDIUMTEXT` can be `16,777,215` bytes (16 MB), so that *should* be OK. You know your data better than I do. I still think you should use `MEDIUMBLOB` or store a path instead (`VARCHAR(1000)`), though. Why do you need to save it in the database, other than making the roundtrip from your queries that much longer? (a query of `SELECT id, picture FROM pictures` will take **much** longer if it uses entire picture contents inside of `picture` rather than a path)